# Java object declaration following return;?

Tags: java, syntax, return, reverse-engineering

I came across some unfamiliar Java syntax while looking at some code from jstl 1.1.2.  It occurs to me the code I'm looking at was reverse compiled by Beyond Compare (or a plug-in thereof), so that might have something to do with it.

The code at the end of the method looks like this:

```
...
p.parse(page.getInputStream(), h);
if(failed)
    return vmFromString("taglib " + prefix + " (" + uri + ") allows only the " + 
    "following taglibs to be imported: " + permittedTaglibs);
return null;
SaxException ex;
ex;
return vmFromString(ex.toString());
ex;
return vmFromString(ex.toString());
ex;
return vmFromString(ex.toString());
}
```

In jstl 1.1, before they refactored the PermittedTaglibsHandler, it looks like this:

```
...
saxparser.parse(pagedata.getInputStream(), permittedtaglibshandler);
if(failed)
    return vmFromString("taglib " + s+ " (" + s1+ ") allows only the " + 
    "following taglibs to be imported: " + permittedTaglibs);
return null;
Object obj;
obj;
return vmFromString(((SaxException) (obj)).toString());
obj;
return vmFromString(((ParserConfigurationException) (obj)).toString());
obj;
return vmFromString(((IOException) (obj)).toString());
}
```

Is this odd syntax just an artifact of the reverse compile, or is there such a thing as meaningful code that follows a return statement?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Comment: this sure is the case of reverse compile! You can't have multiple returns in a function on same level.

Comment: second return is unreachable. I assume that line ex; is useless too. It should give a compile error, but you can force run and it will work correctly, but second return is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is just the exception handler loop customized to handle multiple exceptions - thus the multiple return statements. Its obviously not been translated correctly into Java.